# Iphone displaying the data in word format

Tags: iphone

A call to a webservice returns to me a byte[] which I would like to display in word format on the iphone.

How can I achieve this?
Which view i can use to display the view?

Please provide code samples if possible. Thanks in advance. Please answer as soon as possible.

Comment: What is ‘word format’? A list of words separated by characters in a given set? Microsoft Word? Or…?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what is in the byte[] but assuming they have sent you some string (in ASCII or UTF8 etc) then call use the following init method to init a NSString:

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

You'll need to know the encoding they've used, I'd try 'NSASCIIStringEncoding' and 'NSUTF8StringEncoding' first, but it should be documented somewhere as well.